# PC boots to console instead of desktop?

Tags: startup

While I was using my PC, I had a Vulpix Wallpaper and I was trying to get the GTK window border colors working in LXDE using `Compiz`, so I opened **Compiz Config Settings Manager** and unchecked **Wobbly Windows** to make sure `Compiz Config` was configuring settings properly. When I unchecked it, he window manager seemed to have froze, so I hit power to turn the PC off and then back on. Now, my PC boots to nothing but a blank screen. My PC also flashes some white text at startup before the Lubuntu logo which I'll post a picture right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr8sl.jpg). (I installed the `lubuntu-desktop` package on a regular Ubuntu install with no problems.) A video of the problem can be found [here](http://youtu.be/q-DAFC7_zHI).

Note, with a bit of experimenting, I noticed that I could hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to try and exit a black screen like some other guy who I'd love to give credit to but couldn't find his post, but that brought me into the shell! I logged in to the shell and typed `startx` and I noticed the screen went black, which I hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  and the PC was spewing two lines of text in repetition. I forget what it said, but it was something like:

```
(Something about an invalid preference?)
..
```

I reboot, and I noticed I got the same problem I had in the past! I'd better see if I can do what I did in the past to fix it, I'll post an answer if it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to actionparsnip, his solution can be found [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/188337)!

Step 1: Boot to the login screen.
Step 2: Hit CTRL+Alt+F1 or CTRL+Alt+F3
Step 3: Run the following commands in this order (Try not to do "sudo su" in case it doesn't work):

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
sudo apt-get clean
sudo reboot

Now, check your desktop.
[image: A wild Vulpix appeared on my desktop!]
And there's a Vulpix! (If you don't know what a Vulpix is, it's a character from Pokémon.)

And here's the wallpaper if you want it.
[image]